# qaf chromedriver path application.properties

Tags: selenium-webdriver, path, selenium-chromedriver, qaf

I am new to QAF. what is the format to set path in application.properties? Do I need to include double quotes? single slash or double slash?

```
#set 1 to suppress success log, when 0 it will also show verification success message
report.log.skip.success=0
webdriver.chrome.driver = ??
```

Answer (score 2):

When you are running locally, webdriver required driver executable path to be provided using respective property specified by underlying driver. Most of the case the property is `webdriver.<drivername>.driver`.  For chrome the property is `webdriver.chrome.driver`. It need to set as system property. When you are using qaf, it provides way to set that property through properties file. So the value will be path to chrome driver executable. For examaple:

```
webdriver.chrome.driver=c:/downloads/chromedriver.exe
```

if you have placed driver executable somewhere in your project directory you can provide relative path. For example driver executable is under  <project_dir>/servers/chromedriver.exe then you can set relative path as below:

```
webdriver.chrome.driver=servers/chromedriver.exe
```

Note: for setting driver executable path for drivers other than chrome through property file, you need to add `system` prefix. For instance:

```
system.webdriver.gecko.driver=<gecko-driver-executable-path>
system.webdriver.ie.driver=<ie-driver-executable-path>
system.webdriver.edge.driver=<edge-driver-executable-path>
```

**EDIT:**

QAF `3.0.1b` has integrated web driver manager, so with `3.0.1b` onward driver executable will automatically taken care and you don't need to set any property for driver executable.